# Difference between StackExchange.Redis and ServiceStack.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

Someone can explain the difference about **ServiceStack.Redis** and **StackExchange.Redis** c# libraries?

Comment: Check https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis and https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis

Answer (score 69):

It's VERY important to notice that ServiceStack is a commercially-supported product. See the [free-quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas) on servicestack.net.

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785419/alternative-to-servicestack-redis) mentions the same.

The ServiceStack.Redis NuGet package include the following limitations:

- 10 Operations in ServiceStack (i.e. Request DTOs)
- 10 Tables in OrmLite
- 20 Different Types in JSON, JSV and CSV Serializers *
- 20 Different Types in Redis Client Typed APIs
- 6000 requests per hour with the Redis Client

If you exceed any of these limitations, you'll start receiving exceptions like:

> The free-quota limit on '6000 Redis requests per hour' has been
>   reached. Please see https://servicestack.net to upgrade to a
>   commercial license.

Instead, StackExchange.Redis has no limitations and is under the MIT license.

Comment: Servicestack also does not support cluster mode as of yet (appx 1 year after release of cluster mode), whereas StackExchange client does.

Comment: thank you so much sir for informing us ahead, ... it would have been a massive time bomb disaster had i chosen ServiceStack instead of  StackExchange. Damn!!

Comment: @ifelsemonkey yeah, they hide it to make you dependent until it's too late