# distinguishing features between stackexchange.redis and servicestack.redis

Tags: stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

What are the distinguishing features between **stackexchange.redis** and **servicestack.redis**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between StackExchange.Redis and ServiceStack.Redis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103441/difference-between-stackexchange-redis-and-servicestack-redis)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add more details to narrow the answer set.

But it worth mentioning that a significant difference is that `ServiceStack.Redis` is a commercially-supported product with limitations for free use (See [free-quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas)).

On the other hand, `StackExchange.Redis` has no limitations and is under MIT license.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Actually i wanted to know which one is more performant  and on what basis. Also the features which distinguish them