# Is there TypedClient support in StackExchange.Redis C# client?

Tags: stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis, redisclient

I'm comparing capabilities of ServiceStack.Redis and StackExchange.Redis clients.

I thought that it might be very useful to use `IRedisTypedClient<T>` class of ServiceStack.Redis client.

Just wondering if is there any equivalent of `IRedisTypedClient<T>` class in StackExchange.Redis client which provides auto serialization/deserialization of objects?

Comment: Take into account that ServiceStack.Redis is a commercially supported product. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33105104/122195)